# Run File In Silverlight Navigation Project

Tags: silverlight

How i can open a file that loaded from database
such as Word, Excel, Pdf, ...

my project is not "Out of browser"

```
byte[] Content;
string FileName;
String FileType;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, it's impossible in Silverlight 4 In-Browser unless you install a custom ActiveX that runs processes.

Silverlight 5 will allow Full Trust In-Browser applications which should be able to run processes.

The easiest way to download files in SL4 is having an ordinary SOAP service method that returns the file and saving it to disk with the help of the SaveFileDialog.

In our SL4 project, we have a WCF service that receives ordinary HTTP GET requests and returns HTTP messages that look exactly as HTTP file server responses. When we need to load a file, we navigate the browser to the special URL, the browser sends a GET request, our service returns the file, and, bang, the browser asks user if he wants to open or save the file. This approach requires some extra work to craft the service, but in the end users get the downloads functioning as usual in their favorite browser.